# CreateMap for IEnumerable

Tags: c#, automapper

I have an automapper profile and while working with a senior developer he gave me a pointer to do a create map for an IEnumerable, I got some coded but now I am stuck.

I tried this

```
CreateMap<IEnumerable<BusinessInfo>, IEnumerable<AdminViewModel.Account>>().ForAllMembers(i => i.Ignore());
CreateMap<IEnumerable<BusinessInfo>, IEnumerable<AdminViewModel.Account>>()
                .ForMember(i => i.COMPANY, opt => opt.MapFrom(p => p.Company))
```

but Company is errored because it doesn't contain a definition for Company...
I think I am missing something but I am unsure what it is.

Comment: You'd typically only define a map for the individual models, not the [collection of models](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Lists-and-arrays) `CreateMap<BusinessInfo, Account>()`. AutoMapper would then be able to map the collections. It would be helpful to see the classes you are trying to map.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you mapping `IEnumerable<Type>`?
The reason why it doesn't contain definition of `Company` because it's a collection.

You could of just do mapping for `BusinessInfo` and `AdminViewModel.Account`.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<BusinessInfo, AdminViewModel.Account>()... // do your usual or w/e custom mapping you want.
```

Then you would just do something like...

```
var adminAccountViewModel = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<BusinessInfo>, IEnumerable<AdminViewModel.Account>>(businessInfo);
```

Comment: Well, that is how the lead developer wanted me to do it.  It's a results page.  I'm going to be starting college soon so I don't know why he wants me to do it this way, or even really ...what it means...

Comment: @String_Chez Well yes, if you look at the 2nd snippet, that returns a `collection`. It does what you need to do.

Comment: So you would use the adminAccountViewModel int he controller?  what does (businessinfo) connect to?

Comment: @String_Chez `(businessInfo)` is the object data you grab from somewhere for example from database. And yes you would just do `return View(adminAccountViewModel)` and your RazorView model should be collection of `AdminViewModel.Account`